# How to (efficiently) find the biggest prime factor of a number using Haskell?

Tags: haskell, primes

I am trying to practice Haskell by solving some of the tasks on Project Euler. In Problem 3, we have to find the biggest prime factor of the number `600851475143`, which I had done before in Java a few years back.

I came up with the following:

```
primes :: [Int]
primes = sieve [2..]
    where sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve (filter (\x -> x `rem` p /= 0) xs)

biggestPrimeFactor :: Int -> Int
biggestPrimeFactor 1 = 0
biggestPrimeFactor x =
    if x `elem` takeWhile (< x + 1) primes
        then x
        else last (filter (\y -> x `rem` y == 0) (takeWhile (< x `div` 2) primes))
```

which works great for smaller numbers, but is terribly inefficient and as a result doesn't work well on the number I have been given.
This seems obvious, because the program iterates over all primes smaller than the number divided by 2 (if it isn't prime itself), but I am unsure what to do about it. Ideally I would be able to further restrict the possible checks, but I don't know how to accomplish this.

Note that I am not looking for an "optimal solution", but rather one that is at least moderately efficient for bigger numbers, and simple to understand and implement, as I am still a beginner in Haskell.

Comment: You might find that computing the actual factorization directly, and then returning the last element of that list, is faster than what you're doing. That algorithm should be quite clear to read. Once you've got it, you could take a stab at improving it by trying to work out how to modify it to avoid producing the list and only return the last element of its list directly. But first get the faster but still simple thing working, and only then try optimizing it.

Comment: Related: https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two main sources of slowness here. The easier one to address is the boundary condition in `biggestPrimeFactor`. Checking up to `` p > x `div` 2 `` is asymptotically worse than checking up to `p^2 > x`. But even that is very suboptimal when a number has a lot of factors. The largest factor may be far smaller than `sqrt x`. If you continually reduce the target number as you find factors, you can account for this and speed up the processing of random inputs by quite a lot.

Here's an example of that, including Daniel Wagner's note from the comments:

```
-- Naive trial division against a list of primes. Doesn't do anything
-- intelligent when asked to factor a number less than 2.
factorsNaive :: [Integer] -> Integer -> [Integer]
factorsNaive primes@(p : ps) x
    | p * p > x = [x]
    | otherwise = case x `quotRem` p of
        (q, 0) -> p : factorsNaive primes q
        _ -> factorsNaive ps x
```

A few notes:

1. I decided to have the `primes` list passed in. This is relevant in the next section, but it also allowed me to write this without a helper.
2. I specialized to `Integer` instead of `Int` because I wanted to throw big numbers at it without caring what `maxBound :: Int` is. This is slower, but I decided to default to correctness first.
3. I removed a traversal of the input list. Doing it in one pass is a bit more efficient, but mostly it's cleaner.
4. Strictly speaking, this is correct even if the input list contains non-primes, so long as the list starts at 2, is monotonically non-decreasing, and eventually contains every prime.
5. Note that when it recurses, it either discards a prime or produces one. It never will do both at the same time. This is an easy way to ensure it doesn't miss repeated factors.

I named this `factorsNaive` just to make it clear that it's not doing anything clever with number theory. There are very many things that could be done which are far more complex than this, but this is a good stopping point for understandable factoring of relatively small numbers...

Or at least it is okay at factoring as long as you have a convenient list of prime numbers. It turns out this is the second major cause of slowdown in your code. Your list of prime numbers is slow to generate as it gets longer.

Your definition of `primes` essentially stacks a bunch of filters on an input list. Every prime produced must go through a filter test for each previous prime. This might sound familiar - it's at least O(n^2) work to generate the first `n` primes. (It's actually more because division gets more costly as numbers get bigger, but let's ignore that for now.) It's a known (to mathematicians, I had to look it up to be sure) result that the number of primes less than or equal to `n` approaches `n/ln n` as `n` gets large. That approaches linear as `n` gets large, so generating the list of `primes` up to `n` approaches O(n^2) as `n` gets big.

(Yes, that argument is a mess. A formal version of it is presented in [Melissa O'Neill's paper "The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes"](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/%7Eoneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf). Refer to it for much more rigorous argumentation of the result.)

It's possible to write much more efficient definitions of `primes` that have both better constant factors and better asymptotics. As that's the entire point of the paper mentioned in the parenthetical above, I won't go into the details too far. I'll just point out the very first possible optimization:

```
-- trial division. let's work in Integer for predictable correctness
-- on positive numbers
trialPrimes :: [Integer]
trialPrimes = 2 : sieve [3, 5 ..]
  where
    sieve (p : ps) = p : sieve (filter (\x -> x `rem` p /= 0) ps)
```

This does less than you might think. It doesn't double the speed, as the performance improvement is eventually outweighed by the filter stack mentioned before. This version only removes one filter from that stack, but at least it's the filter that rejects the most inputs in the initial version.

In ghci (no compilation or optimizations, and those can really make a difference), this was fast enough to factor the product of two five-digit primes in a few seconds.

```
ghci> :set +s
ghci> factorsNaive trialPrimes $ 84761 * 60821
[60821,84761]
(5.98 secs, 4,103,321,840 bytes)
```

Numbers with several small factors are handled much faster. Also notice that because the list of primes is a top-level binding, calculations are cached. Running the computation again has the list of primes pre-computed now.

```
ghci> factorsNaive trialPrimes $ 84761 * 60821
[60821,84761]
(0.01 secs, 6,934,688 bytes)
```

That also shows that the run time is absolutely dominated by generating the list of primes. The naive factorization is almost instant at that scale when the list of primes is already in memory.

But you shouldn't really trust performance of interpreted code.

```
main :: IO ()
main = print (factorsNaive trialPrimes $ 84761 * 60821)
```

gives

```
carl@DESKTOP:~/hask/2023$ ghc -O2 -rtsopts factor.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( factor.hs, factor.o )
[2 of 2] Linking factor
carl@DESKTOP:~/hask/2023$ ./factor +RTS -s
[60821,84761]
   1,884,787,896 bytes allocated in the heap
      32,303,080 bytes copied during GC
          89,072 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          29,400 bytes maximum slop
               7 MiB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       326 colls,     0 par    0.021s   0.021s     0.0001s    0.0002s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0002s    0.0004s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.523s  (  0.522s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.021s  (  0.022s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.007s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.545s  (  0.550s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.0%  (0.0% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    3,603,678,988 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  96.0% of total user, 94.8% of total elapsed
```

That dropped the run time from six seconds to a half-second. (Yeah, `+RTS -s` is pretty verbose for this, but it's quick and easy.) I think this is a reasonable place to stop with beginner-level code.

If you want to look into more efficient prime generation, the [primes package on hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primes-0.2.1.0/docs/Data-Numbers-Primes.html) contains an implementation of the algorithm in O'Neill's paper and an implementation of naive factoring that's equivalent to the one here.

Comment: Great answer. In addition to the primes package, the [arithmoi package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.12.0.2/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Primes.html#v:factorise) may also be worth a mention; it is what I would recommend for a non-beginner. On my machine, the primes package is about 40x faster than the code in this answer, but arithmoi is about 15x faster again than the primes package.

Comment: @DanielWagner the primes package is asymptotically faster than this. The bigger you go, the more improvement it'll have.

Comment: Wow! If true, that seems like a bug in arithmoi. It really should be offering the best known algorithms for the things it offers; I'm pretty sure that's the intention, anyway.

Comment: @DanielWagner Oh, sorry. The `primes` package is asymptotically faster than the contents of *this post*. arithmoi definitely is using better tools than either.